# Concatenate two variables into a new one with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

before I explain my question, I'll put here my Json code to facilitate the comprehension.

```
{
    "name": "Servers Rotation",
    "version": 1.0,
    "prefix": ".svr",
    "servers": {

        "server1": {
            "svr": "01x",
            "status": 1,
            "type": "all"   
        },
        "server2": {
            "svr": "02p",
            "status": 1,
            "type": "all"   
        },
        "server3": {
            "svr": "03z",
            "status": 1,
            "type": "all"   
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I'm accessing this JSON and trying create a loop to verify all servers (server1, server2, server3) status to match number 1.

If server[num] status equal 1, then the server is enabled.

```
$.getJSON("servers.json", function(json) {
    var servers_available = Object.keys(json.servers).length;
    for(i = 1; i <= servers_available; i++) {
        if (json.servers.server+i.status == 1) {
            alert(servers_prefix+i.svr + " enabled!");
        } else {
            alert(servers_prefix+i.svr + " disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

But, I'm getting `NaN` as alert response.

What am I doing wrong? Can you help me? Thank you.

Comment: Just a hint to better see what is happening. You can type debugger; on the line above var servers_available = ... and then press F12 to open the developer tools and refresh your page. You will now be able to step through your code and see what is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making three mistakes over here:

- You are using Dot Notation `json.servers.server+i.status`. Here you should use [Bracket Notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation).i.e `json.servers['server'+i].status`
- You are using `servers_prefix` which is `undefined`
- You are using global variable `i`. You should use `let` before it.

Here is the code

```
$.getJSON("servers.json", function(json) {
    var servers_available = Object.keys(json.servers).length;
    for(let i = 1; i <= servers_available; i++) {
        if (json.servers['server'+i].status == 1) {
            alert(json.servers['server'+i].svr + " enabled!");
        } else {
            alert(json.servers['server'+i].svr + " disabled");
        }
    }
});
```

You can do that in a simple way by using :

- `forEach()` on the `Object.values()` instead of `Object.keys()`
- Use Parameter destructuring to get out `svr` and status property of value
- Make use of ternary operators instead of if else statments

```js
let json = {"name": "Servers Rotation","version": 1.0,"prefix": ".svr","servers": { "server1": {"svr": "01x","status": 1,"type": "all"   },"server2": {"svr": "02p","status": 1, "type": "all"  }, "server3": { "svr": "03z", "status": 1,"type": "all"   } }}

Object.values(json.servers).forEach(({status,svr}) => {
  status === 1 ? alert(svr + " enabled!") : alert(svr + " disabled")
})
```

Comment: Hello, I'm getting this error now: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

Comment: Thats because he was using both dot and bracket notation. Now it is edited.

Comment: It's working now! Thank you very much, I'll mark as correct answer in five minutes

Answer (score 0):

try out this one

```
$.getJSON("servers.json", function(json) {
var servers_available = Object.keys(json.servers).length;
for(i = 1; i <= servers_available; i++) {
    if (json.servers["server"+i].status == 1) {
        alert(servers_prefix+i.svr + " enabled!");
    } else {
        alert(servers_prefix+i.svr + " disabled");
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation

```js
var json={
    "name": "Servers Rotation",
    "version": 1.0,
    "prefix": ".svr",
    "servers": {

        "server1": {
            "svr": "01x",
            "status": 1,
            "type": "all"   
        },
        "server2": {
            "svr": "02p",
            "status": 1,
            "type": "all"   
        },
        "server3": {
            "svr": "03z",
            "status": 1,
            "type": "all"   
        }

    }
}

var servers_available = Object.keys(json.servers);
for(i = 1; i <=servers_available.length; i++) {
    
    var a='server'+i;
    if (json.servers[a].status == 1) {
       alert(json.servers[a].svr + " enabled!");
   } else {
       alert(json.servers[a].svr + " disabled");
   }
}
```